# Showmount -e localhost is empty?

Tags: centos, nfs, ldap

I want to make a configuration of LDAP using NFS and I made a file `/etc/exports`:

```
/data    -rw    *(rw,no_root_squash)
```

when I execute this command:

```
showmount -e localhost
```

I got nothing.

Why `showmount` cannot recognize the `/data`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After making the change you need to [exportfs](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/s1-nfs-server-config-exportfs.html) by doing

```
exportfs -a
```

Comment: Thank you, the problem in syntax of export file, I modified it to:  /data    localhost(rw, sync), now it is working.

Comment: mark it as the answer :p